# Lavet type stepper motors design guidelines

Tags: electromagnetism, stepper-motor

For a client we need to provide a Lavet-type stepper motor - I'm looking for some design guidelines - there seems to be very little technical literature on this type of motor.

Wikipedia seems to be it
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavet-type_stepping_motor

Comment: Years ago we had a "too broad" close reason. The "question" you're asking is too vague and would require an enormous amount of effort to answer completely. Please try to narrow your question to one thing that can be objectively answered.

Comment: That gives you a patent number to look up. Which should give some more information. As the Wiki shows, it relies on some asymmetry in the magnetic circuit to set the direction of rotation; in the photo there is some lateral displacement of the poles, in the diagrams, small air gaps at 45/225 degrees. Just take it from there, and hack any quartz clock movement for experiments. (Just noticed : "Applicant : Hatot". I have a slightly earlier Hatot electric pendulum clock, from 1930)

Comment: I have Electrical Machinery by Fitzgerald - which has the Analytical Fundamentals of many DC machines but analytical information on the Lavet design motor is nowhere to be found. I've googled - tried the MIT library etc. 

Reminds me of Lantern Pinions (nothing on that either).

BTW - thanks for the help.

Comment: Horology tends not to follow general engineering disciplines; the attitude to bearing fits is ... looser, and (apart from lantern pinions) you'll see cycloidal gearing instead of involute. So I'm not surprised a general "electrical machinery" text has nothing useful. Horology sources might.

Comment: Lantern pinions :) - also something that has no engineering data on.